# BLOB data management in MySQL during update to null?

Tags: mysql, storage, blob

I have several transactional tables that has a logically-placed `text` and a `blob` column in MySQL.  After a period of time these data columns are not needed on rows older than X days.  I need to be as storage-aware as possible.  This is on multiple nodes in a cluster that have limited local and NFS storage, so keeping them as files not viable.

Two obvious solutions, which is the better (if any) way of ensuring freed blob table storage:

1. On some schedule, update all the rows where date < X days ago set the text and blob columns to null.  Does this actually free the blob data storage in the "hidden" table?
2. Keep these blobs in a separate table and then delete from the table where date < X days ago.

Keeping in good schema form, I don't want to have a blob-table per transaction table as to keep the transaction keys independent, and I don't want to have associative/smart/compound keys in a single blob table.

What mechanism works best for temporal blob storage in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have InnoDB or NDB storage engine in your database. In this case, by default, you will never give back the disk space after update/delete rows or tables (including BLOB columns).

There is only way to solve the problem. Set

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

in `my.cnf`, and you will have separate files for each table. Then, the second way (drop table when it's no needed) will restore storage space.

Comment: Good info and forgot that on innodb. The isam tables do re-use storage on delete, yes? can I recover space using an isam sub-table with delete (are blobs inlined in those tables?). Low write volume so the table locking should not be an issue.

Comment: For re-use MyISAM storage, run `OPTIMIZE TABLE table1, table2...` Of course, these tables will be locked all the time.

Comment: But on MyISAM (which I'm considering for this separate blob table) regardless of the table locking, new inserts will eventually fill old deleted records?